# How to aggregate a result by condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection based on which I need to calculate a score which is as simple as this.

Calculate score for all students  in my collection
If a student belongs to class 'A' or 'B' he gets a score of 5 else if he belongs to class 'C' or 'D' he gets 4

Student:

```
{
    name:"Aster",
    classes:['A','B']
}
```

Aggregation doesn't allow $in operator on $cond so how do i proceed

Ps:Excuse. Brevity sent on the go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this can cover totally your problem, but you can use `$setIsSubset` in Mongo 2.6:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { name: 1 , 
                 grade: { $cond: [{$setIsSubset: ["$classes", ["A","B"]]}, 5, 4]}     
               } 
   }])
```

In case `classes` can be either string or array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { name: 1 , 
                 grade: {$cond: [{$or: [{$eq: ["$classes", "A"]}, 
                                        {$eq: ["$classes", "B"]}, 
                                        {$setIsSubset: ["$classes", ["A","B"]]}]}, 
                                 5, 4]}     
               } 
   }])
```

Comment: Well done. Probably should not assume that the other values are "C" or "D". But well done and good thinking.

Comment: Thank @NeilLunn. Of course the prob may not be solved by assuming other values are "C" or "D". I just want to point out that there are other available options now http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/

Comment: I was only pointing out you could edit the answer to cover this. But basically `$setIsSubset` is the best operator to use here.

Comment: This is the answer thanks for the awesome response.This is exactly what I needed

Comment: Only one question though @anhlc .Is there an operator to do so between a string and an array. Since a single string does not constitute an array that is required by setIsSubset or any other workarounds

Comment: You can try to cast the string as array of 1 element by put the string in []. I didn't try yet so can you let me know if it works

Comment: @humblerookie, if classes is always a string, try grade: { $cond: [{$or: [{$eq: [ "$classes", "A" ] }, { $eq: [ "$classes", "B" ] } ]}, 5, 4]}

Comment: @anhlc Thanks but it wouldn't be scalable since my superset would consitute of 100's of values and forming such a query even if possible just goes against sanity.Infact this was my first horrible way of doing it before your setisSubset suggestion.I managed to structure my document to force the field to be an array which seems the right way to go about it. Cheers